# Gravitational potential of a cube

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, physics

I want to write code that calculates the gravitational potential of an arbitrarily shaped celestial body. To understand the calculation, I started with an easy shape: a rectangle (or a cube). I realised this was allready hard enough, so I researched in the Internet and found a work of this problem. I found the equation:

[image]

Where `v` is

`v = Subscript[x, 1]*Subscript[x, 2]*Subscript[x, 3]`,

and the $D_i$ are the lenghs of the edges of the cube.

I have 2 questions (but the first one will be answered too if the second one gets answered):

I try to understand how this sum looks like, but I dont quite get how this summation over the Integration Limits works. I guess every little $x_i$ must vanish after the last step.

So my actual question is:

How can I code these integration limit brackets and sum over them?

Comment: [source of the mysterious equation here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3857.pdf)

Comment: Similar question was already asked here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160755/compute-int-limits-x-1x-2-int-limits-y-1y-2-int-limits-z-1z-2/160757#160757

Comment: the interesting aspect of OP's question is  : how to retranscript a formula found in a book in Mathematica code, in a way that respects the formulation of the book ? The idea is to do a minimal effort retranscription too.

Comment: "every little xi must vanish after the last step" = mysterious text

Comment: What I mean is, that the x_i are only some variables for the integration, but the Potential, after all calculations are made, should only contian: G, rho, X_i and D_i.

Answer (score 2):

This is `Not` a answer of yours `Question` its only alternative solution.

```
G = 1;
ρ = 1;
a = 1;
b = 1;
V[X_, Y_] := -G*ρ*NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(X - x)^2 + (Y - y)^2], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // Quiet

n = 1/15;
ListContourPlot[Partition[Flatten[Table[{x, y, V[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2, n}, {y, -2, 2, n}]], 3], 
Contours -> 40]
```

Gravitational potential of a square:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find that the notations used in the formula are misleading.

- the inner summation is a normal summation
- The outer "summation" describes in fact a list of **nested** (hence the use of the instruction `Fold[]` in the code below) replacement rules associated with summations.

Here is the transcription in Wolfram Language (= Mathematica) :

```
sumOverIBaseElt[i_] = v/x[i] Log[x[i]+r] - (x[i]^2)/2 ArcTan[v/(r*x[i]^2)] /. 
{v -> x[1] x[2] x[3], r -> Sqrt[x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2]};

sumOverI=Sum[sumOverIBaseElt[i],{i,1,3}];

potentialV[X1_,X2_,X3_]=Fold[
(
   (#1 /. #2 /. sign -> 1)
   -(#1 /. #2 /. sign -> -1)
)&,
sumOverI,
{
x[1]-> sign D1-X1,
x[2]-> sign D2-X2,
x[3]-> sign D3-X3
}];

ContourPlot[
      Evaluate[potentialV[x,y,0] /. {D1->1,D2->1,D3->3}],
      {x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},
      PlotLegends->Automatic,
      Exclusions -> None,
      Epilog -> {Dashed,Line[{{-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,-1}}]}]
```

[image]

Calculate the gravitational field vectors.

```
StreamPlot[
Evaluate[{
    D[potentialV[x, y, 0] /. {D1->1,D2->1,D3->3}, x],
    D[potentialV[x, y, 0] /. {D1->1,D2->1,D3->3}, y]}],
{x, -2, 2},{y, -2, 2}, 
StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

[image]

**EDIT version 2**

also possible, and finally simpler :

```
potentialV[X1_,X2_,X3_]=
    (v/xi Log[xi+r] - (xi^2)/2 ArcTan[v/(r*xi^2)] /. 
    {v->x1 x2 x3,r->Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]}) /. 
    {{xi-> x1},{xi-> x2},{xi-> x3}} //
    (Plus @@ #)& //
    ((# /. x1->D1-X1)-(# /. x1->-D1-X1))& //
    ((# /. x2->D2-X2)-(# /. x2->-D2-X2))& //
    ((# /. x3->D3-X3)-(# /. x3->-D3-X3))&;
```

-> same result

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there some other term to discribe the outer summation then, since its not a normal summation? I want to understand whats going on here, but I need to know what I am looking for.

Comment: @MichelK. It's more like a composition of functions  than a summation. A big difference is that a composition leads to a exponential increase of the number of terms (composition x->f[x] - g[x] n times leads to 2^n terms. In our case f and g are replacement of some terms x_i). Hope I'm relatively clearer

Comment: After thinking for quite a while, I still dont get it, sorry. But thanks for your time. Where is the composition? It would help me, if someone has the time to explain the steps/the scheme this Equation wants me to do, if I would calculate this by hand. Also this equation produces 48=3*2^4 Terms.  :(

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation of how the square brackets are used (as is the case in definite integration) is correct, then the following code calculates $V(X_1,X_2,X_3)$.

```
(* localize symbols *)
Block[{x, r, Dd, X, G, ρ},
 (* expression inside the Sum inside the square brackets *)
 With[{v = Times @@ Array[x, 3]},
  f[i_] := (v/x[i]) Log[x[i] + r] - ((x[i]^2)/2) ArcTan[v/(x[i]^2 r)]
  ];
 (* the expression inside the square brackets *)
 With[{sum = Plus @@ Array[f, 3]},
  g[j_] := Plus @@ (
     {1, -1} (sum /. {
         {x[j] -> Dd[j] - X[j]},
         {x[j] -> -Dd[j] - X[j]}
         }
       )
     )
  ];
 (* actual definition of V *)
 V[args__] := With[{params = Array[X, 3]},
   With[{sum = Plus @@ Array[g, 3]},
    -G ρ sum /. Thread[params -> {args}]
    ]
   ]
 ]
```

Evaluating `V[a, b, c]` returns a lengthy expression (which I won't reproduce here). It seems, though, that the assertion in the question

> "[...] I guess every little xi must vanish after the last step"

is not confirmed.

---

**End notes**

Verify that indeed `V` performs the calculations in the right order:

Evaluating

```
V[X[1], X[2], X[3]] == -G ρ Plus @@ (
  (
    (* perform the operation implied by the square brackets *)
    Plus @@ ({1, -1} (
      With[{v = Times @@ Array[x, 3]},
        (* expression inside square brackets *)
        Plus @@ Array[(v/x[#]) Log[x[#] + r] - ((x[#]^2)/2) ArcTan[v/(x[#]^2 r)] &, 3]
       ] /. #))
           (* construct the limits of the square brackets *)
   ) & /@  Array[{{x[#] -> Dd[#] - X[#]}, {x[#] -> -Dd[#] - X[#]}} &, 3]
 )
```

returns

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Can you add into yours answer a  gravitational potential plot?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I don't think I can, because as I explain in the answer, the (implementation of the) expression for `V` contains free parameters `x[j]` (lower-case `x`'s)

Comment: So this means this formula is wrong? This Potential doesnt make any sense, if there are free parameters besides X[i]. There must be some other approach, which satisfies my assertion, right? But anyways thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @MichelK. you're welcome; I think the notation is misleading or the function of the brackets is different from the the usual